# Is there anyway to relocate to a dungeon without walking to it's location in the game world?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Some of the Dungeons are located in areas I've never explored, and it would be ideal if I could enter dungeons without needing to explore these locations and unlock their way points. Not just for the sake of saving time, but also because I usually save unexplored areas for secondary characters so I still have new content to experience on a second play through.

Is there anyways to enter a dungeon without walking to the dungeon in the game world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

If you are part of a team and haven't reached the location yet, when the team enters the dungeon you will be prompted with a dialog saying that your team mates have 'Entered a Story Zone' and you'll be given the option to 'Join' and then you'll be teleported to the first part of the dungeon instance.

I don't think this works if existing players are inside the dungeon, only if they are entering the zone 'fresh'.

Comment: Correct. Last night I got disconnected while inside a dungeon, and because I had not yet discovered the area it was in, I had to walk all the way to the dungeon.